# Loading json with volley in fragment of a sliding menu

Tags: android, json, fragment

I'm trying to load a json list in a fragment of a sliding menu. 
I just tried to move the activity codes to fragment. but it doesn't work.
in activity all thing is right, and it works.
actually I'm not professional with fragments. please tell me what is a fragment.

It is what i did, please tell me what's the mistake i made:

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import info.androidhive.volleyjson.app.AppController;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public static ListView gridView_url;
    ListViewAdapter_URL adapter;
    JSONArray jsonarray;

    // json object response url
    private String urlJsonObj = "http://www.musiclistening1.blogsky.com/";

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        gridView_url = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_url);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
// Loading.............................................
        makeJsonObjectRequest();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {

        showpDialog();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                            try {
                                jsonarray = response.getJSONArray("music1");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        adapter = new ListViewAdapter_URL(getActivity(), jsonarray);

                        gridView_url.setAdapter(adapter);


                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // hide the progress dialog
                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }

    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hidepDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: plz post your logcat...

Comment: You are not parse json array.... 1st you parse json array than pass to adapter.....!!!

Comment: i did that. I'm using volley library. I saied: It workes in activity. I just didn't use hashmap , because it slows down the app

Comment: Post logcat and code for ListViewAdapter_URL adapter.